# Batch DOS copying last lines of a file limited by 65 536 characters

Tags: xml, windows, batch-file, copy

I have a heavy XML file of 1Go having the following structure:

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows-1252'?>
 <ext:BookingExtraction>
     <Booking><Code>2016Z00258</Code><Advertiser><Code>00123</Code<Name>LOUIS VUITTON</Name></Advertiser></Booking>
     <Booking><Code>2016Z00259</Code><Advertiser><Code>00124</Code<Name>Adidas</Name></Advertiser></Booking>
 </ext:BookingExtraction>
```

As the structure is really simple my goal is to get the 150 last lines of an XML file copy them into new file and add the opening tag  in the first line to have a well formed XML.

The algorithm works fine but some line having more than 65 536 characters are splitted in several lines. 
I read that DOS limit the number of character per line at 65 536. This is why it add a carriage enter character after this 65 536 characters.

The result is that the final XML is not well formed because of the carriage enter in the middle of the line.
For instance:

```
 <ext:BookingExtraction>
     <Booking><Code>2016Z00258</Code><Advertiser><Code>00123</Code><Name>LOUIS VUIT
TON</Name></Advertiser></Booking>
</ext:BookingExtraction>
```

I tried to remove the characters carriage enter but it does not work.
Do you have any idea how could I fix this?

```
`@echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

::Get XML file
for /r %%a in (extractedBookings_BookingWithoutUnitsContent_PRD_*.xml) do (
    ::echo "%%~dpa" and full path is "%%~nxa"
    set fileName="%%~nxa"
)


::Get the 150 last line of the file 
    echo File path: "%fileName%"    
    for /f %%i in ('find /v /c "" ^< "%fileName%"') do set /a lines=%%i
    echo nb lines: "%lines%"
    set /a startLine=%lines% - 150
    echo Start line "%startLine%"
    more /e +%startLine% "%fileName%" > extractedBookings_BookingWithoutUnitsContent_PRD.xml



::adding opening tag to the new file
    echo ^<?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows-1252'?^> > newFile.xml
    echo ^<ext:BookingExtraction^> >> newFile.xml

::Get the final file
   type extractedBookings_BookingWithoutUnitsContent_PRD.xml >> newFile.xml
   type newFile.xml > extractedBookings_BookingWithoutUnitsContent_PRD.xml`
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: It's better to parse XML as structured markup, rather than this thing you're doing now.  Edit your question to show the structure of your XML, and what you want to keep and what you want to dispose; and I'll see if I can help you find a more graceful solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is confusing; the "DOS limit the number of line at 65 536 characters" phrase is imprecise. When the output of *more command* is redirected to a disk file, it waits for a character after 65536 *lines*, and such character is inserted in the output. Also, the max line length in FIND command is 1070 characters (accordingly to [this site](http://ss64.com/nt/find.html)), so I guess that your file have shorter lines. You just need a method that can cleanly output more than 64K lines.

The solution below is basically your same code, but it uses a combination of `set /P` command to skip the first lines and a `findstr` command to show the rest, instead of your `more +%startLine%` command.

```
@echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

::Get XML file
for /r %%a in (extractedBookings_BookingWithoutUnitsContent_PRD_*.xml) do (
    ::echo "%%~dpa" and full path is "%%~nxa"
    set fileName="%%~nxa"
)


::Get the 150 last line of the file 
    echo File path: "%fileName%"    
    for /f %%i in ('find /v /c "" ^< "%fileName%"') do set /a lines=%%i
    echo nb lines: "%lines%"
    set /a startLine=%lines% - 150
    echo Start line "%startLine%"

    REM Use a code block to read from redirected input file (and write to output file)
    < "%fileName%" (

       rem adding opening tag to the new file
       echo ^<?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows-1252'?^>
       echo ^<ext:BookingExtraction^>

       REM Skip the first total-150 lines
       for /L %%i in (1,1,%startLine%) do set /P "="

       REM Copy the rest
       findstr "^"

    ) > extractedBookings_BookingWithoutUnitsContent_PRD.xml
```

This method may still fail if an input line is longer than 1023 characters, because this is the limit of `set /P` command.

Comment: Hi @Aacini. So the limitation is due to the use of the  `set /P`. I tried you algorithm and faced the same problem. I was thinking about using the function `FileOpen`. Do you think it could solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

As I commented earlier, 'tis better to parse XML as a hierarchical structure, rather than as predictably-formatted flat text.  If that flat text is beautified, uglified, minified, whatever, a flat text scraper will fail.

Your example XML is still a little ambiguous, so I'm assuming you've got a single `<ext:BookingExtraction>` tag with a ton of `<Booking>` child nodes you wish to whittle down to the last 150.

Before your example XML can be parsed, though, (besides fixing the missing `>` in `</code>`) we need to massage it slightly by defining the namespace to which `ext` belongs.

Before:

```xml
<ext:BookingExtraction>
```

After:

```xml
<ext:BookingExtraction xmlns:ext="http://localhost">
```

Although strictly speaking that's probably a bogus namespace, it's good enough to make the XML parse-able nevertheless.  We can do this programmatically by reading the XML into a variable and performing a regex replace.  After that, it's just a simple matter of removing child nodes within a `while` loop until you reach your 150-element goal.

Save this with a .bat extension, replace "test.xml" with the location of your XML file, and run it.

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
@echo off & setlocal
cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0" "test.xml" "output.xml"
goto :EOF
@end // end Batch / begin JScript hybrid code

var args = { infile: WSH.Arguments(0), outfile: WSH.Arguments(1) },
    fso = WSH.CreateObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject'),
    file = fso.OpenTextFile(args.infile, 1),
    xml = file.ReadAll(),
    DOM = WSH.CreateObject('MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0'),
    ns = 'xmlns:ext="http://localhost"',
    xpath = '/ext:BookingExtraction/Booking';

file.Close();
DOM.loadXML(xml.replace(
    /<(ext:BookingExtraction)>/i,
    function($0, $1) { return '<' + $1 + ' ' + ns + '>' }
));

if (DOM.parseError.errorCode) {
    var e = DOM.parseError;
    WSH.StdErr.WriteLine('Error in ' + args.infile + ' line ' + e.line + ' char '
        + e.linepos + ':\n' + e.reason + '\n' + e.srcText);
    WSH.Quit(1);
}

DOM.setProperty('SelectionNamespaces', ns);

while (DOM.selectNodes(xpath).length > 150) {
    var node = DOM.selectSingleNode(xpath)
    node.parentNode.removeChild(node)
}

DOM.save(args.outfile)
```

---

... Or it might be a little easier just to strip out the `ext:` namespace and replace it later.  Here's a batch + PowerShell hybrid script that demonstrates.  It's not as fast as the batch + Jscript hybrid, and it has a side effect of beautifying all tags whether you want them indented or not.  But it does have the advantage of simplicity.

```js
<# : batch portion
@echo off & setlocal

set "infile=test.xml"
set "outfile=out.xml"

powershell -noprofile "iex (${%~f0} | out-string)"
goto :EOF
: end batch / begin PowerShell hybrid #>

[xml]$xml = (gc $env:infile) -replace "ext:"
$xpath = "/BookingExtraction/Booking"
$deleted = 0

while ($xml.selectNodes($xpath).Count -gt 150) {
    $node = $xml.selectSingleNode($xpath)
    [void]$node.parentNode.removeChild($node)
    $deleted++
}

write-host "Removed $deleted ndoes" -f magenta

$xml.save($env:outfile)
(gc $env:outfile) -replace "BookingExtraction", "ext:BookingExtraction" | sc $env:outfile
```

---

**Edit:** if dealing with large files (1GB+), maybe it would actually be better to trim the fat as flat text, rather than manipulating as structured object data.  If you want the last 150 lines, I think it'd be more efficient to start at the bottom and work backwards, rather than starting at the top and skipping millions of lines.  Opening the XML file with .NET methods will allow you to seek to the end of the file nearly instantly, then walk up.  Try this batch + PowerShell script and see whether it works more efficiently for you:

```js
<# : batch portion
@echo off & setlocal

set "infile=test.xml"
set "outfile=out.xml"

powershell -noprofile "iex (${%~f0} | out-string)"
goto :EOF
: end batch / begin PowerShell hybrid #>

$lines = 150
$found = 0
$reader = new-object IO.StreamReader((gi $env:infile).FullName)
$stream = $reader.BaseStream
$xml = $reader.ReadLine(), $reader.ReadLine()

$pos = $stream.Seek(0, [IO.SeekOrigin]::End)

while ($found -le $lines) {

    $reader.DiscardBufferedData()
    $stream.Position = --$pos
    $char = $reader.Peek()

    if ($char -eq -1) { break }
    else { if ($char -eq 10) { $found++ } }
}

$reader.DiscardBufferedData()
$stream.Position = ++$pos

$xml += $reader.ReadToEnd()
$reader.Close()

$xml -join "`r`n" | out-file $env:outfile
```

Comment: Hi @rojo. Thank you for your answers. The second algorithm works perfectly for small files but when I launch it for big file (1go), I got a `System.OutOfMemoryException`. The initial algorithm I posted does not cause this problem but it adds carriage return in the middle of XML lines.

Comment: The second algorithm worked perfectly. The `System.OutOfMemoryException` was due to an computer not powerful enough. Thank you very much @rojo.

Comment: @Bob I didn't realize you were working with 1GB XML files.  I now see the value of working with the data as flat text.  Goodness!  I added a 3rd solution that uses .NET methods to seek the last 150 lines from the bottom of the document.  See whether it works on the computer that was giving you the System.OutOfMemoryException.  I'm curious.

Comment: The third algorithm is much faster and does not block the computer.  I added `echo %time%` at the beginning and a `Get-Date` at the end of the code to measure how long it takes. It takes about 45 min which is much better than before. The last solution which the closer to my initial idea is definitely the best. Thank you very much.