# Split a XML into multiple XMLs

Tags: xml, batch-file, vbscript

I am looking for a batch/VBScript which can split a large XML with multiple tags into multiple XML files. Please see details below.

---

**Input XML:**

```xml
<Shipment>
----some data- say 001-------
</Shipment>
< Shipment>
---- Some data- say 002-------
</Shipment>
```

****Output XML 1:****

```xml
<Shipment>
---some data- say 001-------
</Shipment>
```

**Output XML 2:**

```xml
<Shipment>
----some data- say 002-------
</Shipment>
```

---

My code below is not working for some reason. Can anyone help me with logic?
I was trying intitally to get data with input having only single `<shipment>` tag.

**Code:**

```batch
    ::Read Xml file
    set f_xml=input2.xml    
    for %%i in (%f_xml%) do (
        set xmlfilename=%%~ni
    )

    ::Write XML file 
    for /f "tokens=1* delims=]" %%b in ('type "!xmlfilename!" ^| find /n /v ""') do (
        if /i *%%c*==*[Shipment]* set inblock=1
        if !inblock!==1 (
            if *%%c*==** (echo.) else (echo %%c)
            if /i *%%c*==*[/Shipment]* set inblock=0
        )
    )
    echo. 
) >> output.xml
```

Comment: You are looking for someone to write this code for you. When you ask on Stack Overflow, you need to show your effort on solving the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your free suggestion, am new to scripting and hence asked for logic in question not code completely

Comment: Your code doesn't work because you have an unmatched closing parenthesis. Also, how large exactly is "large"?

Answer (score 1):

It's better to parse and objectify XML and other such structured markup than to hack and scrape it as flat text. The `cmd` interpreter unfortunately doesn't offer much for parsing XML natively, but it's easy enough to borrow from other scripting engines that do.

PowerShell is particularly well-suited to handle XML. You can read an XML file as text, then cast that data as an XML object simply by prefacing it with the `[xml]` accelerator. Handy, right? From there, select all `Shipment` nodes using an XPath expression; then for each, clone to a fresh XML object and save.

Here's a hybrid Batch + PowerShell script demonstrating this. Save this with a .bat extension and salt to taste.

```js
<# : Batch portion
@echo off & setlocal

set "xmlfile=test.xml"

powershell -noprofile "iex (${%~f0} | out-string)"
goto :EOF

: end Batch / begin PowerShell hybrid code #>

[xml]$xml = "<root>$(gc $env:xmlfile)</root>"

$xml.SelectNodes("//Shipment") | %{
    $x = new-object xml
    $x.AppendChild($x.ImportNode($_, $true))
    $x.Save("shipment{0:D3}.xml" -f ++$i)
}
```

The drawback to this method is that your large XML file must be loaded into memory before even the first chunk is saved.  Depending on how large "large" is, you might have to resort to a stream reader and flat text scraping to speed up execution (similar to what you originally intended, but with a more efficient reader than Batch `for /f`).  That flat text scraping should be avoided if possible (see [this ugly example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35724783/1683264)).  But if you're working with an XML file that can be measured in gigs, you might have no other choice.

Answer (score 0):

A very basic approach to writing sibling nodes to individual files with VBScript is to read the input file as XML and export the XML text of the individual nodes as plaintext:

```vb
Set xml = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
xml.Async = False
xml.Load "C:\path\to\input.xml"

If xml.ParseError <> 0 Then
    WScript.Echo xml.ParseError.Reason
    WScript.Quit 1
End If

i = 1
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
For Each n In xml.SelectNodes("//Shipment")
    outfile = fso.BuildPath("C:\path\to", "output" & i & ".xml")
    Set f = fso.CreateTextFile(outfile)
    f.Write n.Xml
    f.Close
    i = i + 1
Next
```

Note that this code doesn't add an XML declaration to the output files. If you want that you need to add it yourself.

Note also that the above code assumes that the input file is valid XML (i.e. the sibling nodes have common single root node).